# How do I get the phone book to the list in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

nativescript-contacts-lite module is not working in my app.please tell me a different method.

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-contacts-lite

is not working my app.

```
let desiredFields = ['display_name','phone','thumbnail','email','organization'];

console.log('Loading contacts...');
let timer = new Date().getTime();

Contacts.getContactsWorker(desiredFields).then((result) => {
  console.log(`Loading contacts completed in ${(new Date().getTime() - timer)} ms.`);
  console.log(`Found ${result.length} contacts.`);
  console.dir(result);
}, (e) => { console.dir(e); });
```

I'm building an angular project in cmd 
`tns create contacts --ng` then add my code to "app.component.ts" after this error " lines

iPhone: CONSOLE INFO file: ///app/vendor.js: 578: 36: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled.

Waiting for signal.

> CONSOLE WARN file: ///app/2af32b54d949cd652b47.worker.js: 28922: 14:
>   Objective-C class name "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl"
>   is already in use - using
>   "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl2" instead. 2019-09-12 16:
>   52: 22,081 nsplaydev [7621: 1393673] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception"

i take this in terminal

Comment: What is returning the results.length?, or are you reciving an error? in that case which error is? giving us more feedback will help us to help you

Comment: Please try to elaborate what is the issue with your existing method.

Comment: I'm building an angular project in cmd
tns create contacts --ng
then add my code to "app.component.ts" after this error " Enes iPhone: CONSOLE INFO file: ///app/vendor.js: 578: 36: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
CONSOLE WARN file: ///app/2af32b54d949cd652b47.worker.js: 28922: 14: Objective-C class name "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl" is already in
use - using "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateImpl2" instead.
2019-09-12 16: 52: 22,081 nsplaydev [7621: 1393673] PlayLiveSync: Uncaught Exception" i take this in terminal

Comment: Uncaught Exception has nothing to do with the warning above. If you are using Preview app, you can not use this plugin. You should build the application locally in order to use plugins those are not packed with preview app - such as this one.

Comment: thanks for the information you provided @Manoj

Comment: So where do you suggest I work ? now ı working tns preview